# Does WCF cache stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql, wcf

I have a WCF service that my client makes a call to telling it to run `storedprocedure1`, with `param1, param2`, etc.

When the WCF service gets this call, it instantiates a class that instantiates a DAO class.
The DAO class creates the connection, loads the parameters into a `SqlCommand` object, then executes the object.

After finishing, it closes the `SqlConnection`, but does not close or dispose the DAO class, because there are multiple procedures it needs to run.

Here's the problem. If I edit `storedprocedure1` and then call it through the WCF service, the changes I made in `storedprocedure1` are not reflected until I restart the WCF service. Its like the `storedprocedure1` is cached in WCF.

Has anyone else experienced this and is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key likely lies in this statement:

> but does not close or dispose the DAO
>   class

Without seeing the code for your DAO class it's hard to say, but it seems more likely that the query result is being cached by your data access layer than it does that it's being cached by WCF.

Either way, it really has nothing to do with the stored procedure, it's just caching the result of executing the stored procedure. If you changed the data instead of changing the procedure, the same problem should exist - you get back stale data.

Comment: don't think so.  the SQLCommand is instantiated inside a using clause.  Also when I close the connection, I dispose of it.  I have changed my dao class to implement IDisposable, we'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: You were right.  Even though I was disposing of the SqlConnection and SqlCommand, not disposing of the DAO was allowing the WCF to cache it, or keep the execution plan, or something.

I had the dao as a private variable in the class that the WCF called.  So I made the following changes; 1) changed my DAO class to implement IDisposable and closed and disposed of the SQLConnection there; 2)Created my dao inside a usings clause and when that wasn't feasible, disposed of the dao in a try/finally.  So now it works.  Thanks for challenging me on the obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I think the WCF service is caching the results of the stored procedure.

See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443.aspx

Comment: Output caching isn't enabled by default - it seems likely OP would be aware of it if that were happening.

Comment: here is the attribute for the WCF class

Comment: here is the attribute for the WCF class
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
but I never explicitly enable caching for HTTP or in my connection string.

I should mention that the problem happens when running WCF from ServiceHost in a console app, which is for testing.  
I've not seen this problem in the IIS hosted instance.  We seldom change the stored procedures when deployed to IIS